# Comprehension question about "Interpolation from Curve Mapping" node

Tags: animation-nodes, interpolation

I do not understand properly the behavior of the "Interpolation from Curve Mapping" node.
At all interpolation nodes the output value of the corresponding Evaluate node is "0" at positon "0" and "1" at position "1". Except for the "Interpolation from Curve Mapping" node; at this node the output value is "-0.5" at positon "0" and "1.5" at position "1", even though the first point of the interpolation curve is at "0,0" and the last is at "1,1".
Why behaves the "Interpolation from Curve Mapping" node like this?

[image: Interpolation from Curve Mapping]

Comment: I see unexpected behaviour as well.  Not the same as yours.  In my experiment I can produce negative values on both ends even though I expect non negative values.

Comment: May I add a picture to your question which is mentioned above in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

This (at the first glimpse) unexpected behavior exists because otherwise you can't create certain types of interpolations. eg the 'back' interpolation with an overshoot would not be possible.

This is why AN (Animation Nodes addon) remaps the Y values: 0.25 -> 0; 0.75 -> 1

All values below 0.25 or above 0.75 will be the 'overshoot' (and you need this overshoot quite often in motion graphics..)

Fortunately, Blender draws the horizontal lines in the curve mapping editor so that it is easy to see where 0.25 and 0.75 are.

Use the Debug Interpolation node to see the mapping performed by Animation Nodes.

[image]

If the remapping would not exist, there would just not be enough space in the node ui to have control over the overshoot:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of why [you need this overshoot quite often]?

Comment: It is mainly used for Motion Graphics. eg when you want to animate an object that flys into the scene it looks much better if it goes over that target and comes back afterwards.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. What is "that" which you implemented at first and what is "it" to which you reverted? What is "that" for which there is a reason (2nd sentence)? And what is "AN?" Please make this a complete answer.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear... I hope it is a bit clearer now.. Tell me if not

Comment: I read what you wrote. I understand the general concept of overshoot.  I do not understand how this assists in the creation of overshoot.  Do you have something already written or a simple node example which illustrates the usefulness of this? A link to written words ...  or nodes example?

Comment: edited the answer again... I hope it is clear now, because I have no idea how to explain that better.

Comment: If the problem is that, if the remapping would not exist, there is not enough space in the node ui, than why you can not simply use the zoom function? If you set the "clipping options" (dot icon) accordingly, than you can zoom out as you need it.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! I didn't know that to be honest. I just tested it but it does not really look better in my opinion. And I find it relatively 'hard' to setup. Will see, maybe I will change this remapping in a later release.

Comment: That's right, you have to know how it has to be configured. But the zoom-variant also has some advantages: 1. No astonishment at the mapping of the values (the output value at x corresponds to the adjusted y value). 2. No restriction of the curve point values (now the values are (visually) limited to 0,-0.5;1,1.5) 3. No mapping to remapping, when you create the curve (as in my case) from a specified list of x-y-values. Perhaps it would be the easiest solution to show a tutorial in the documentation how to zoom out. Many thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: That convinced me. The next version will contain the new behavior. thanks :)